# smartctl; need help to recover usb disk

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive, smartctl

I have a 2TB usb disk. I can not see it anywhere, can not mount it anyway. Here is the smartctl output. I am using ubuntu-22.04. How I rescue/use my usb disk? Any help

```
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu-Precision-7730:~$ sudo smartctl -x /dev/sda -d scsi -T permissive
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.19.0-46-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               NAND
Product:              USB2DISK
Revision:             0.00
Compliance:           SPC-2
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
>> Terminate command early due to bad response to IEC mode page
scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
Read Cache is:        Unavailable
Writeback Cache is:   Unavailable

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Error Counter logging not supported

scsiModePageOffset: response length too short, resp_len=4 offset=4 bd_len=0
Device does not support Self Test logging
Device does not support Background scan results logging
```

Here is the output of `lsusb` and `lsusb -t`

```
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu-Precision-7730:~$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID ffff:1201  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6717 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5832 Broadcom Corp. 5880
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu-Precision-7730:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Chip/SmartCard, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

And the output of `lsblk` is:

```
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu-Precision-7730:~$ lsblk 
NAME       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0        7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1        7:1    0  31,6M  1 loop /snap/bash-language-server/27
loop2        7:2    0 134,8M  1 loop /snap/cmake/1288
loop3        7:3    0 134,6M  1 loop /snap/cmake/1299
loop4        7:4    0 302,3M  1 loop /snap/code/132
loop5        7:5    0 302,9M  1 loop /snap/code/133
loop6        7:6    0 118,2M  1 loop /snap/core/15419
loop7        7:7    0 118,2M  1 loop /snap/core/15511
loop8        7:8    0  55,6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2751
loop9        7:9    0  55,7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2785
loop10       7:10   0  63,4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1950
loop11       7:11   0  63,4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop12       7:12   0  73,8M  1 loop /snap/core22/750
loop13       7:13   0  73,9M  1 loop /snap/core22/766
loop14       7:14   0   582M  1 loop /snap/datagrip/170
loop15       7:15   0 583,9M  1 loop /snap/datagrip/171
loop16       7:16   0 895,5M  1 loop /snap/dataspell/50
loop17       7:17   0 895,4M  1 loop /snap/dataspell/53
loop18       7:18   0 244,8M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2760
loop19       7:19   0 244,5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2800
loop20       7:20   0   113M  1 loop /snap/git-ubuntu/474
loop21       7:21   0 221,9M  1 loop /snap/gitkraken/209
loop22       7:22   0 230,3M  1 loop /snap/gitkraken/212
loop23       7:23   0 349,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137
loop24       7:24   0 349,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
loop25       7:25   0 466,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/111
loop26       7:26   0 485,5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop27       7:27   0  81,3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop28       7:28   0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop29       7:29   0  37,1M  1 loop /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2
loop30       7:30   0 325,1M  1 loop /snap/inkscape/10536
loop31       7:31   0 325,5M  1 loop /snap/inkscape/10539
loop32       7:32   0  67,3M  1 loop /snap/jupyter/6
loop33       7:33   0 436,3M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20/7
loop34       7:34   0 437,2M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-98-qt-5-15-6-core20/9
loop35       7:35   0 290,6M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4
loop36       7:36   0 319,5M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/7
loop37       7:37   0 424,2M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8
loop38       7:38   0 323,5M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-core20/14
loop39       7:39   0 448,7M  1 loop /snap/kf5-5-104-qt-5-15-8-core22/9
loop40       7:40   0 198,3M  1 loop /snap/kturtle/89
loop41       7:41   0 198,3M  1 loop /snap/kturtle/91
loop42       7:42   0  51,3M  1 loop /snap/openstackclients/256
loop43       7:43   0  51,7M  1 loop /snap/openstackclients/315
loop44       7:44   0  68,9M  1 loop /snap/powershell/237
loop45       7:45   0  45,9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/638
loop46       7:46   0  53,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19361
loop47       7:47   0  68,9M  1 loop /snap/powershell/240
loop48       7:48   0  12,3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
loop49       7:49   0   428K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/57
loop50       7:50   0  53,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop51       7:51   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
loop52       7:52   0 295,7M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2344
loop53       7:53   0 320,4M  1 loop /snap/vlc/3078
sda          8:0    1     0B  0 disk 
nvme0n1    259:0    0 953,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1
│          259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2
           259:2    0 953,4G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                     /
nvme1n1    259:3    0 476,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1
│          259:4    0 476,5G  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p2
           259:5    0   480M  0 part
```

Comment: when you plug the disk in, what's the output of `lsusb` and `lsusb -t`

Comment: @JaromandaX , I have added the output of lsusb and lsusb -t in my question

Comment: looks like `Bus 001 Device 002: ID ffff:1201` is the USB disk, it's `Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M` ... ouch, that's slow, and an "obsolete" USB id - is that supposedlt a 2TB **flash** drive? I think it's as fake as Donald Trumps political career

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, Thanks. It was working fine previously. Then I have done something terrible during formatting. I wanted make two partitions inside the drive but somehow messed up. I am not sure what I have done. Just wondering if there is any way to recover it.

Comment: is that a USB thumb/flash drive or a USB->SSD bridge? the fact that it shows up as `Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage` suggests it should be present as a disk drive though

Comment: Not sure what I did exactly. Is there any way to repair it?

Comment: I have no idea what "it" is ... keep asking you if it's a flash/thumb drive or some sort of USB to SATA bridge ... and ... crickets - what brand is it? how much did it cost? I think you've got a fake - chances are, the act of formatting it broke it

Comment: It is a usb storage device. I do not know the difference between " flash/thumb drive or some sort of USB to SATA" . The brand is "NAND"  and product is: "USB2DISK". Still I am not sure if it was a fake because, I used it to store and transfer different types of data (movies/tabular data/genomic data etc).

Comment: a flash/thumb drive is like a tiny device - a USB to SATA device would have like a 2.5" disk drive - have you tried the device in a different USB port? a different computer?

Comment: Thank you. Then it is a USB to SATA device. Yes, I tried with different port and computer but no results.

Comment: How old is this device? Did you ever have it working? what's the output of `lsblk`? you said you "formatted" it. What is it you did exactly

Comment: I wanted to create a partition inside this usb disk drive. My intention was to have two partitions one for backup of my pc and the other for general use. But before finishing the partitions I removed the disk or shut down the computer or something similar. It was taking too much time. I added the output of the lsblk in my question.

Comment: `sda          8:0    1     0B  0 disk` ??? have you tried `fdisk /dev/sda` - you said the disk isn't detected, if it turns out to be `/dev/sda` then I'm not sure why you said it's not detected

Comment: fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No medium found